# Why was whoopsie not disabled in stable 12.10?

Tags: error-handling, whoopsie

I was wondering about this for quite a while.

I've been using ubuntu for quite a long time now, and I knew apport showed these "internal error detected" messages, without actually being noticably affected by something, but this was always in alpha/beta/RC versions of Ubuntu.

As far as I know, apport was always disabled when the distro hits release. Why did this not happen for Ubuntu 12.10? Is this a bug, or is this planned?

Nonetheless, it gives a messy impression imo

EDIT: apparantly, this was also the case for Ubuntu 12.04, and it's not apport, but whoopsie.

Comment: The "An Error Occured" type messages are normally from whoopsie; check out this discussion https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2012-August/001658.html

Comment: Thanks, I can relate to the pros and cons pointed out in this discussion

Answer (score 0):

Apport has always been enabled in released versions. ubuntu is made of software and software is made of bugs, so it's best to make it easy to report these bugs, especially in released versions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in previous versions (prior to 12.04) this was not the case. There was always an update the day before release that disabled these excessive error messages

Comment: Yeah Apport used to turn itself off after release.